# In iOS where should objects be created if not in view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class (that gets data from NSNotificationCenter, process it and send it to NSNotificationCenter again) that I like to make an instance of as soon my app is started. I could do it from a view controller but that seems awkward since they are not related. So where do you find it appropriate to create objects that are not directly related to UI but should last the lifetime of the application?

Comment: `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Comment: As mad as I might be for suggesting it, what's wrong with a singleton?  No reason to mess your delegate with all this cruft unrelated to the duties of an App Delegate.

Comment: @CodaFi I'm new to iOS but the singleton would first be initialized at the first call right? If that is the case messages from NSNotificationCenter could be lost right?

Comment: Initialize it in main then.  Nothing against sending `[MySingleton sharedInstance]` at startup.

Comment: @CodaFi OK but I guess I could just create my (non-singleton) object once in main too, right? And if that is the case the big Q is such objects should be in main or the AppDelegate!? :)

Comment: Well, I would argue that ideally, the setup for the `main()` is one extra line of code for a global instance that separates logic from delegation, rather than 4 or 5 lines of setup for a non-singleton object that mixes logic and state into a delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put items that require to be alive for the entire lifecycle of the running app in in the AppDelegate.h/m file.

Comment: singletons are more effective lifecycle-independant containers than the app delegate.

Answer (score 2):

As tempting as it is to just shove code into the App Delegate **resist the urge**.  An Application Delegate should ideally be as far removed from normal application execution as possible.  The only reason it is a global instance is so that it can act as a delegate between the application and the system.  For the sake of maintaining a separation of powers, initialize a singleton instance in `main()` and have that react to notifications.

Comment: @matt Delegate abuse is a serious issue, but it can be cured with a little hope and lots of electro-shock therapy (otherwise known as anti-Java therapy).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to put that kinda stuff in a ViewController, the AppDelegate usually seems like a nice place to put it.

Comment: No it's not.  I would argue that the delegate is only for responding to system events, not for creating state or initializing objects.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in the app delegate. The app delegate is one of the first objects created (well before any of your view controllers!) and it is globally visible to all other objects. So if you instantiate this other class and make that instance a property of your app delegate, it too is globally visible to all other objects!

As I say in my book (http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_global_visibility):

> A public property of the app delegate, which you are free to create, is globally visible by virtue of the app delegate being globally visible (by virtue of the shared application being globally visible).

And even if you don't need visibility (because you are using notifications), the app delegate is the longest-lived object you've got; it is created as the app launches and is never destroyed (until the app is killed).